# Make chrome extension icon disappear

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, icons, manifest

I was trying to create a chrome extension that doesn't have an icon but to function in the background, is there any way to it?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.

You should modify you manifest as follows:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Kittens new generation",
  "description": "Adds kittens to all web pages",
  "version": "0.1",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

For more info please refer to [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).